# If you run fast RAM at a slower clock speed, will the latency timings improve?

Tags: memory, performance, speed, latency, ddr

I am buying a motherboard and CPU that support DDR4 2400 memory.

For approximately the same cost, I can buy either of the following two types of memory:

DDR4 2400 memory with timings of 16-16-16-39.
DDR4 2666 memory with timings of 19-19-19-43.

If I install the 2666 memory into the 2400 system, will the timings improve?  Or are the timings "locked", even if the 2666 memory is running at 2400?

If the answer depends on the specific hardware involved, is there a way (preferably in Linux) to determine the actual timings that are being used in a running system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes... If the memory reports it is capable that, and most reputable RAM does. Looking in the BIOS should tell you what the RAM timings are in most cases.

To see the memory timings in Linux, there are a few methods, the first uses 'lshw' which is installed in many distro's

```
acejavelin@BlazingIcicle:~$ sudo lshw -C memory
[sudo] password for acejavelin:          
..,deleted...

      *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3600 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: CL18-22-22 D4-3600
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3600MHz (0.3ns)
... Deleted...
```

Or using i2c-tools, although this one isn't quite as accurate on newer boards such as my MSI MPG X570 that uses A-XMP, but it will show all the standard timings the RAM supports...

sudo modprobe eeprom
decode-dimms

Which will yield something like this:

```
Decoding EEPROM: /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/eeprom/0-0052
Guessing DIMM is in                              bank 3

---=== SPD EEPROM Information ===---
EEPROM CRC of bytes 0-125                        OK (0xC408)
# of bytes written to SDRAM EEPROM               512
Total number of bytes in EEPROM                  512
Fundamental Memory type                          DDR4 SDRAM
SPD Revision                                     1.1
Module Type                                      UDIMM
EEPROM CRC of bytes 128-253                      OK (0x58B6)

---=== Memory Characteristics ===---
Maximum module speed                             2666 MHz (PC4-21300)
Size                                             16384 MB
Banks x Rows x Columns x Bits                    16 x 17 x 10 x 64
SDRAM Device Width                               8 bits
Ranks                                            1
AA-RCD-RP-RAS (cycles)                           19-19-19-43
Supported CAS Latencies                          20T, 19T, 18T, 17T, 16T, 15T, 14T, 13T, 12T, 11T, 10T

---=== Timings at Standard Speeds ===---
AA-RCD-RP-RAS (cycles) as DDR4-2666              19-19-19-43
AA-RCD-RP-RAS (cycles) as DDR4-2400              17-17-17-39
AA-RCD-RP-RAS (cycles) as DDR4-2133              15-15-15-35
AA-RCD-RP-RAS (cycles) as DDR4-1866              13-13-13-30
AA-RCD-RP-RAS (cycles) as DDR4-1600              11-11-11-26

---=== Timing Parameters ===---
Minimum Cycle Time (tCKmin)                      0.750 ns
Maximum Cycle Time (tCKmax)                      1.600 ns
Minimum CAS Latency Time (tAA)                   13.750 ns
Minimum RAS to CAS Delay (tRCD)                  13.750 ns
Minimum Row Precharge Delay (tRP)                13.750 ns
Minimum Active to Precharge Delay (tRAS)         32.000 ns
Minimum Active to Auto-Refresh Delay (tRC)       45.750 ns
Minimum Recovery Delay (tRFC1)                   550.000 ns
Minimum Recovery Delay (tRFC2)                   350.000 ns
Minimum Recovery Delay (tRFC4)                   260.000 ns
Minimum Four Activate Window Delay (tFAW)        21.000 ns
Minimum Row Active to Row Active Delay (tRRD_S)  3.000 ns
Minimum Row Active to Row Active Delay (tRRD_L)  4.900 ns
Minimum CAS to CAS Delay (tCCD_L)                5.000 ns
Minimum Write Recovery Time (tWR)                19.500 ns
Minimum Write to Read Time (tWTR_S)              4.500 ns
Minimum Write to Read Time (tWTR_L)              13.000 ns

---=== Other Information ===---
Package Type                                     Monolithic
Maximum Activate Count                           Unlimited
Post Package Repair                              One row per bank group
Soft PPR                                         Supported
Module Nominal Voltage                           1.2 V
Thermal Sensor                                   TSE2004 compliant

---=== Physical Characteristics ===---
Module Height                                    32 mm
Module Thickness                                 2 mm front, 2 mm back
Module Reference Card                            A revision 0

---=== Manufacturer Data ===---
Module Manufacturer                              Undefined
Part Number                                      Undefined
```